# Where can I leave my laptop in Iquitos, Peru so it is safe?

Tags: safety, peru, south-america

I am coming to Iquitos, Peru in December. I will be travelling in the area for about a month, wild-camping, canoeing, fishing etc.

I need to take my laptop with me so I can work on the way (it is almost 48 hours). However, my laptop would definitely not survive my traveling so I need to find a place to leave it for 1 month in Iquitos. I don't know anyone there and am not sure whom I can trust as it is my first time in South America.

**Question**: Is there a place or an institution where I could leave it and be sure it will be there when I return? I wouldn't mind paying some reasonable amount for it.

**What I have thought of so far**: the police, someone at the airport, someone at church, someone from Couchsurfing, some upper-class hotel...?

Comment: I'd argue that if your work can cope with you being out of contact for 1 month that those extra days working while you are in transit to/from Peru are not critical to your job.  And if you want to argue that this is time you can bill for, I'd argue that a some overtime before/after your trip would be a lot more productive and a lot less worrisome than leaving your laptop in some random location.

Comment: I understand your comment but that doesn't answer my question..

Comment: @JanPisl the comment is a frame challenge on your question - do you really *need* to take your laptop with you and go to all this trouble to keep it safe or can you do some overtime or another alternatives and *not take it* with you.

Comment: Would it not make more sense (if you have to take it with you) to ship it back home once you arrive? You won't need especially quick delivery since as long as it beats *you* back then you're all good?

Comment: @JanPisl I subscribe to a hierarchical theory of packing for a trip.  1) Things critical to your trip or critical to you need to be on your person at all times.  2) If circumstances require it, you should be able to drop your hand luggage and run with no regrets.  3) Don't ever expect to see your checked luggage (or its contents) again.   IMHO your desire to leave your work laptop in Iquitos during your trip places it in the third category.  So without a really compelling reason I would always advise to leave it at home.  Also what compelling reason do those places have to keep it safe?

Comment: Shipping it home could present its own set of problems.  Due to exploding "hoverboards" and Samsung Notes, there can be strict regulations about shipping devices containing lithium-ion batteries, and often there are outright prohibitions.  If you decide to ship your laptop home, do extensive research first to make sure you _can_ legally ship it home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options.  As you've noted, the airport doesn't have luggage storage.  Hotels/hostels often will store for a fee, or worst case, book a 'night' there even if you don't use it, and just 'check in' and store your bag.

[Flying Dog Hostel Iquitos](https://www.booking.com/hotel/pe/flying-dog-hostel-iquitos.en-gb.html?aid=356980;label=gog235jc-1DCAsosQFCGWZseWluZy1kb2ctaG9zdGVsLWlxdWl0b3NIM1gDaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEM2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuAKF57HuBcACAQ;sid=cedab82ba6566b2a964ed38b56f95641;dist=0&keep_landing=1&sb_price_type=total&type=total&) is one example that offers luggage storage:
[image]

And according to [Wikitravel](https://wikitravel.org/en/Iquitos), the Emperador Terraza Hotel also offers this service.